# Entity Framework Core DbContext not returning child object which is a FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My `DbContext` is not returning a specific child object which referenced by a FK.
The object I want it to populate is `Step.PVTag`. How can I include it in the query? Should I turn off lazy-loading? If yes, how do I do it?

```
public async Task<Recepi> Get(short id)
{
        var context = _formulaDBContext;
        {
            var entity = await context.Recepies
                .Include(r => r.Step)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.Nodes)
                         .ThenInclude(n => n.SPTag)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);

            return entity;               
        }
}
```

My classes:

```
public class Recepi : BaseModel
{
    public Recepi()
    {
        Step = new List<Step>();
    }

    public short FormulaGroupId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RecepiId")]
    public List<Step> Step { get; set; }
}

public class Step : BaseModel
{
        public Step()
        {
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
        }

        public short RecepiId { get; set; }
        public short PVTagId { get; set; }
        public Operator Operator { get; set; }

        public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Activity Activity { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("StepId")]
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public class Node : BaseModel
{
        public short StepId { get; set; }        
        public short SPTagId { get; set; }        

        public string Value  { get; set; }
        public TagMetaData SPTag { get; set; }        
        public TagMetaData PVTag { get; set; }
        public Operator Operator { get; set; }        
}
```

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include multiple nested sub-properties, write the `Include()` twice, like this

```
var entity = await context.Recepies
    .Include(r => r.Step).ThenInclude(s => s.Nodes).ThenInclude(n => n.SPTag)
    .Include(r => r.Step).ThenInclude(s => s.Nodes).ThenInclude(n => n.PVTag)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.Id == id);
```

Comment: Thankyou. It works now. I was looking for this last five days.